# Error when using GAE bulkloader: Unable to download kind stats

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I try to use the bulkloader, I get the following output:

```
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20120828.105614
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20120828.105614.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20120828.105614.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to sortexpr.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
[ERROR   ] Unable to download kind stats for all-kinds download.
[ERROR   ] Kind stats are generated periodically by the appserver
[ERROR   ] Kind stats are not available on dev_appserver.
```

I can view my data in the GAE dashboard. I have one kind with two fields, both of which hold strings. One thing that seems possible is that the kind stats haven't been generated yet. Does someone know how often they are generated?

I've seen some discussion of this issue in various places, but haven't found an actual solution. Any ideas? Failing a bulkloader solution, are there other ways to get my data off the google server onto my computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It works now, ~24 hrs later. This is consistent with the problem being that kind stats are generated infrequently.